# Not able to get friends email id from facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

I am using facebook sdk 4.4.0.

Now, when I fetch a list of my friends who are using my app at that time, I need to retrieve their `email`. But I am not getting it.

```
   GraphRequestBatch batch = new GraphRequestBatch(
                    GraphRequest.newMyFriendsRequest(token,
                            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONArrayCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(JSONArray jsonArray,
                                                        GraphResponse response) {
                                    System.out.println("jsonArray: "
                                            + jsonArray);
                                    System.out.println("GraphResponse: "
                                            + response);
                                    try {

                                        mArrayUserFriendsList = new ArrayList<UserFriendsList>();

                                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                                            mFriendsList = new FriendsList();

                                            JSONObject c = jsonArray
                                                    .getJSONObject(i);

                                            mFriendsList.setname(c
                                                    .getString("email"));

                                            mArrayFriendsList.add(mFriendsList);

                                            mUFriendsListAdapter = new UFriendsListAdapter(
                                                    getActivity(), mArrayFriendsList);
                                            user_friends
                                                    .setAdapter(mFriendsListAdapter);
                                            mFriendsListAdapter
                                                    .notifyDataSetChanged();

                                        }

                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                }
                            }), GraphRequest.newMeRequest(token,
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,
                                                GraphResponse response) {
                            System.out.println("meJSONObject: "
                                    + object);
                            System.out.println("meGraphResponse: "
                                    + response);

                        }
                    }));
            batch.addCallback(new GraphRequestBatch.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onBatchCompleted(GraphRequestBatch graphRequests) {
                    // Log.i(TAG, "onCompleted: graphRequests "+ graphRequests);
                }
            });
            batch.executeAsync();

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields",
                    "id,first_name,email,gender,birthday");
         //  request.setParameters(parameters);
         //  request.executeAndWait();
```

When I write `name` instead of `email` then it gives me the name of friendlist.

How can I get email info?

Comment: You can not get the email address of friends. They would have to login to your app and grant it permission to access their email address.

Comment: i am fetching only those list who has login into my app and grant permission. So with the above code i am fetching friends who has already login into my app.
But i am not able to get the email id of them./

Comment: I think you need to use their own user access token to fetch the email.

Comment: Means? How can i perform that?

Comment: Get their email address when they login, and store it. Or extend and store their access token, so that you can look it up in your database, and use it to request each friend’s email address individually.